# What can one do with the Android Wear AOSP? Is it possible to build/flash a rom on a wearable?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, android-wear

I've previously modified/built/flashed the Lollipop AOSP for a Nexus 5 but now I want to modify/build/flash the Android Wear AOSP for an LG watch but have no idea where to begin - I can find no instructions online nor in the Android Wear AOSP source about how to do this.

If its the same process as building a phone AOSP then there are still multiple unanswered questions such as:

- After downloading the Android Wear AOSP source and then typing "lunch" doesn't list any additional/different configurations. The lunch menu lists the same things for the Android Wear AOSP as it does for a standard AOSP, so how can the Wear AOSP be built?
- Are drivers for different watches necessary to be downloaded to include in the build process?
- Can a wearable device be flashed using fastboot flash XYZ.img just as a phone can?
- Are system images available for download for wearables?

I'm confused why Google have released an Android Wear AOSP if there doesn't appear to be any instructions or means of actually doing anything with it.